# Showing a sequence is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I was given the following problem for a review for an exam and am unable to solve it:

*Prove that $\frac{1}{x+1} \le k \left[ \ln\left(x+\frac{1}{k}\right)-\ln(x) \right] \le \frac{1}{x}$ for $1 \le x \lt \infty, k \ge 1.$*

A hint was to use the mean value theorem, but I am unable to find bounds on the function if I try to use the theorem:

If we look at the interval $[k, k+1]$, then we set up our fraction and wind up with $(k+1)\ln(x + \frac{1}{k+1}) - k\ln\left(x+\frac 1 k \right) - \ln(x)$, which I can't find a way to bound by either $\frac{1}{x+1}$ or $\frac{1}{x}$.

Can someone give me a hint as to how I can relate these bounds to my sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $1\leq x<\infty$ and $k\geq 1$. Consider the interval $[a,b]$, where $a=x$ and $b=x+1/k$. Then, by the MVT, there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{c}=\ln'(c)=\frac{\ln(b)-\ln(a)}{b-a}=\frac{\ln(x+1/k)-\ln(x)}{1/k}=k(\ln(x+1/k)-\ln(x)).
$$

But you know that 
$$
x<c<x+\frac{1}{k}\leq x+1.
$$
Hence, 
$$
\frac{1}{x+1}<\frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{x},
$$
which is what you want.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! I see I was approaching the problem entirely wrong, thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)